cannot get stripe checkout
Here is the approach I followed for the checkout in my ecommerce application.But it doesn't pass data to the backend and get the session.url.I think the issues is with the data structure.Help me to fix it.
import "./shoppingCart.css";
import ArrowBackIosIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ArrowBackIos';
import MediaControlCard from '../../../components/Cards/shoppingCartCard';
import CustomerNavbar from "../../../layout/navbar/Customer navbar/Customer navbar";
import Footer from "../../../layout/footer/footer";
import {loadStripe} from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import CustomizedButton from "../../../components/Button/button";
import axios from "axios";

const getStripe = () => {
    let stripePromise = '';
    if (!stripePromise) {
        stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY);
    }
    console.log(stripePromise);
    return stripePromise;
}

function Cart() {
    const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
    const [totalAmount, setTotalAmount] = useState(0);
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const storedCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
        if (storedCart) {
            setCart(storedCart);
        }
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        let total = 0;
        cart.forEach(item => {
            total += item.productPrice * item.amount;
        });
        setTotalAmount(total);
    }, [cart]);

    const removeFromCart = (itemId) => {
        const updatedCart = cart.map(item => {
            if (item.id === itemId) {
                if (item.amount === 1) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    return {...item, amount: item.amount - 1};
                }
            }
            return item;
        }).filter(Boolean);
        setCart(updatedCart);
        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(updatedCart));
    }

    const redirectToCheckout = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        const stripe = getStripe();
        const lineItems = cart.map(item => ({
            price_data: {
                currency: 'lkr',
                product_data: {
                    name: item.productName,
                },
                unit_amount: item.productPrice * 100,
            },
            quantity: item.amount,
        }));

        console.log(lineItems);

        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:9000/payment/customerPayment/create', {
                lineItems: lineItems
            });
            setLoading(false);
            console.log(response.data.url);
            window.location.href = response.data.url;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error creating checkout session:', error);
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }


    return (
        <>
            <CustomerNavbar/>
            <div className="cartOuter">
                <div className="cardspace">
                    {cart.map(item => (
                        <MediaControlCard key={item.id} item={item} removeFromCart={removeFromCart}/>
                    ))}
                </div>

                <div className="cartInner">
                    <div className="arrow">
                        <ArrowBackIosIcon/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="totalText">
                        <p>Total Amount</p>
                        <p className="amount">Rs {totalAmount.toFixed(2)}</p>
                        <CustomizedButton
                            onClick={redirectToCheckout}
                            disabled={isLoading}
                            hoverBackgroundColor="#0aaf0b"
                            style={{
                                color: '#ffffff',
                                backgroundColor: '#057007',
                                width: '7.5em',
                                height: '2.25em',
                                fontSize: '0.85em',
                                padding: '0.5em 0.625em',
                                borderRadius: '0.625em',
                                border: 'none',
                                marginTop: '0.25em',
                                marginBottom: '2em',
                            }}>
                            {isLoading ? "Loading..." : "Buy Now"}
                        </CustomizedButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <Footer/>
        </>
    );
}
export default Cart;

service.ts

/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
import { Injectable, BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { CustomerPayments} from './payment.entity';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { CustomerPaymentDTO, Data} from './dto/cutomerPaymentDTO';
import { ILike } from "typeorm";
import { Query } from 'express-serve-static-core';
import {Stripe} from 'stripe';
import { Cart } from './stripe/Cart.model';


@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  [x: string]: any;
  private stripe;
  
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(CustomerPayments)
    private readonly customerPaymentManagement: Repository<CustomerPayments>,
  ){
    this.stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY,{
      apiVersion: '2024-04-10'
    })
  }

  async createCustomerPaymentSession(data: Data[]){

    //const dataArray = Object.values(data);

    const line_items:Data[] = data.map(item =>(
      {
        price_data: {
          currency: item.price_data.currency,
          product_data: {
            name: item.price_data.product_data.name,
          },
          unit_amount: item.price_data.unit_amount * 100,
        },
        quantity: item.quantity,
      }
    ))

    const session = await this.stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      mode: 'payment',
      line_items,
      success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/success',
      cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/cancel',
    });

    return session.url;
  }

  async getAllCustomerPayments(): Promise<CustomerPayments[]>{
    return await this.customerPaymentManagement.find();
  }

  async getCustomerPaymentById(id: any): Promise<CustomerPayments | null>{
    return await this.customerPaymentManagement.findOneById(id);
  }

  async searchAllPayments(query: Query): Promise<CustomerPayments[]> {
    console.log('Received query:', query);
    const keyword = (query.query as { keyword?: string }).keyword;
    try {
      const filteredPayments = await this.customerPaymentManagement.find({ where: { customerName: ILike(`%${keyword}%`) } });
      console.log('Filtered suppliers:', filteredPayments);
      return filteredPayments;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error occurred while searching payments:', error);
      return [];
    }
  }

}


dto
export interface Data {
    price_data: {
        currency: string;
        product_data: {
            name: string;
        };
        unit_amount: number;
    };
    quantity: number;
}

api.controller
  @Post('payment/customerPayment/create')
  async createCustomerPaymentSession(@Body() data: any) {
    return this.paymantClient.send({ cmd: 'CREATE_CUSTOMER_PAYMENT' }, data);
  }

app.controller
@MessagePattern({ cmd: 'CREATE_CUSTOMER_PAYMENT' })
  async createCustomerPaymentSession(@Body() data: any) {
    return await this.customerPaymentManagement.createCustomerPaymentSession(data);
  }

Here is the approach I followed for the checkout in my ecommerce application.But it doesn't pass data to the backend and get the session.url.I think the issues is with the data structure.Help me to fix it.I tries to get inbuilt checkout page

What is the error you're facing?
